# Assign continuous stream to variable and process the variable

Tags: shell-script, logs, tail, command-substitution

I'm trying to make an analyzer for a custom log that I have.

My log file has a duration timestamp (in ms) which I want to filter out from the others and send me the logs that take over a threshold timestamp over email or IM.

Currently, I'm assigning the output of a `tail -f` command piped with many other commands, to a variable and then attempting to process the value in the variable. But I haven't been successful to even simply `echo` the log.

Here's the simplest form of the script I'm using :

```
log=$(tail -f $logFile | grep ms | rev | cut -c 3- | rev | awk '{ if($NF > $monitorTreshold) {  print $0 }  }')
for q in log; do
  echo "Query : $q"
done
```

Comment: The pipeline will never exit as `tail -f` will continuously send more data. You will have to either parse the whole log in one go, or a portion of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Kusalananda mentions, the pipeline will never exit and so `$log` will never get a value.

In addition, you may see `grep` buffering output because it's not going to `stdout`.

So you need to process the data live by having the pipeline feed directly into a shell loop, similar to:

```
tail -f $logFile | grep --line-buffered ms | rev | cut -c 3- | rev | awk '{ if($NF > $monitorTreshold) {  print $0 }  }' | while read q
do
  echo "Query : $q"
done
```

Be warned, in shells such as `bash` then variables set inside that loop will not be visible outside the loop.  In `ksh93` they will be set.  If you need to set such variables in `bash` then you might need to look at co-processes.